# Code behind function not being fired in IE but in Firefox - C#, .Net, IIS

Tags: c#, .net, iis

Does anyone have any clue why a code behind function would work in Firefox but not in IE.
It seems that the client side wouldn't effect what's going on in the code behind.

Comment: Not without some sample code.

Comment: It doesn't. You're probably missing the root cause of the actual problem and seeing a side-effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Event handling in the code behind of a `WebForm` is triggered by a posting of data.  Depending on the control, how that posting gets triggered can differ.  Sometimes it's done through JavaScript.  So here's a few things to check for:

1. Is scripting enabled in IE?
2. If this is a custom control running JavaScript, is the JavaScript compatible with IE?
3. Are there any plugins or malware loaded in the IE browser that is interfering with the integrity of the post data?

If you post some more specifics or your code, we should have a better idea of what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

What's function? Is javaSctipt enabled in IE?